# SQL always encrypted and dump of migration scripts for validation

Tags: flyway

I have two issues I can't figure out how to accomplish in Flyway without forking the repo and we'd like to avoid that.

**Issue #1**. Sql Server Always Encrypted connection, how do we override or inject enough information so that Flyway can setup the database connect to an Always Encrypted database. The connection needs to connect to Azure Key Vault to get a token for use for encryption/decryption but this additional setup that is above the the standard User Name/Password the connection string needs. Also, you can't pass these values on the connections string.

[More details here on how this would be done in JDBC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-always-encrypted-with-the-jdbc-driver?view=azuresqldb-current) as I'm not a Java person.

**Issue #2**. Is there a way to retrieve the full list of SQL statements that are about to run during the migration and after all the "placeholders" are resolved? We need a way to check all the SQL scripts to ensure the scripts don't run specific commands such as CREATE USER, DROP DATABASE, etc. as we running this in a controlled environment and though that those commands work great during development, they can't be run in PRODUCTION. In Production the database user will have elevated privileges so we need to check the scripts before running them. I see the Dry Runs Pro feature but that just writes to a file. We'd like to get this data back on a callback and then we can validate it prior to the migration running.

Comment: Please file feature requests for these in the Flyway issue tracker: https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues

Comment: Thanks Axel but I don't see them as feature requests but clarification if there are ways to use the existing version for my use cases. So should this be moved to github then?